# Eloquent use index (IndexRaw) not working properly with join and has

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a pretty big query written using Eloquent query builder and I want to add indexes to use. 
I do not want to rewrite the query using DB because it can cause a lot of problems in application if I made something wrong (this query is part of many queries in the system) and it cost a lot of time (query is big)

**I simplify query just to show the issue:**

```
$model = $this->model->setConnection($connection);
if(!is_null($forceIndex)) {
    $model = $model::IndexRaw('USE INDEX('.$forceIndex.')');
}
$model = $model->has('advertiser')
dd($model->toSql());
```

**Query is:**

```
select * from table USE INDEX(allowed_index, status_index) where (select count(*) from `advertisers` where `table USE INDEX(allowed_index, status_index)`.`advertiser_id` = `advertisers`.`id`) >= 1
```

as you can see builder is stupid and substitutes `table USE INDEX(allowed_index, status_index)` as a table name.

Thanks for any help!

FYI: I'm using Laravel 4.2 here if it matters

Answer (score 2):

I found solution

```
$model = $this->model->setConnection($connection);
if(!is_null($forceIndex)) {
    $model = $model->from(\DB::raw('table USE INDEX('.$forceIndex.')'));
}
```